# Pre Android 4.2 Webview clicks don't align or respond properly

Tags: android, webview

I'm new here and I haven't posted before. Please educate me if I've not done it correctly.

We have a web app built for mobile browsers that works great. We're wrapping it in a WebView for Android and when it's used on a device that's running JellyBean the controls respond as expected when clicked. However, running the same app on devices with ICS and prior, some of the controls don't respond at all, or you have to click above and left of the control to get to to register. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've seen this on Android, in the manymo.com simulators for versions 4.3 and version 4.4.  Somehow, the click event does not get triggered, even though the event has been rebound.  But, I haven't isolated the cause yet.  Some of our clicks still work and some don't.